# add photo with blob to database sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, blob

I'm trying to add photo to my database(sqlite3)
but it give me this Error:

```
    self.cur.execute (sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
sqlite3.OperationalError: 7 values for 6 columns
```

and this is my code that i try with:

```
def open_image ():
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename (initialdir = "/", title = 'Select A File', filetypes = (('png files', '*.png'), ('jpg files', '*.jpg')))
    app.filename = file_name
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open (app.filename).resize ((80, 80), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    image_label.configure (image = image)
    image_label.image = image
    image_entry = Entry (app, textvariable = file_name)
    image_entry = {'image' : image}

def add_contact():
    db.insert_contact (app.filename, firstname_text.get (), lastname_text.get (), phone_number_text.get (), email_address_text.get (), address_text.get ())
    contact_list.delete (0, END)
    contact_list.insert (END, image_entry.get (), firstname_text.get (), lastname_text.get (), phone_number_text.get (), email_address_text.get (), address_text.get ())
    clear_contacts ()
    populate_list ()
```

and finally this is my database:

```
def convertToBinaryData(self, filename):
    #Convert digital data to binary format
    import os
    # THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    # my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, filename)
    # print (THIS_FOLDER)
    print ('this is the filename: ', filename)
    file = open (filename, 'rb')
    blobData = file.read ()
    return blobData

def insert_contact (self, image_entry, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email_address, address):
    sqlite_insert_blob_query = "INSERT INTO contacts (image_entry, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email_address, address) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
    
    empPhoto = self.convertToBinaryData (image_entry)
    data_tuple = (empPhoto, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email_address, address)
    self.cur.execute (sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
```

what should I do to resolve this?

"""""""""LAST CHANGES"""""""""

my database:

```
import sqlite3

class Database:


    def convertToBinaryData(filename):
        #Convert digital data to binary format
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            blobData = file.read()
        return blobData

    def __init__ (self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, photo BLOB, firstname text, lastname text, phone_number NUMERIC, email_address text, address STRING)")
        self.conn.commit ()

    def fetch_contact (self):
        self.cur.execute ("SELECT * FROM contacts")
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

    def insertBLOB(self, photo, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email_address, address):
        def convertToBinaryData (filename):
             #Convert digital data to binary format
            with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                blobData = file.read()
            return blobData
        # try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('store.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Connected to SQLite")
        sqlite_insert_blob_query = """ INSERT INTO contacts
                              (id, photo, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email_address, address) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""

        empPhoto = convertToBinaryData (photo)
        # Convert data into tuple format
        data_tuple = (photo, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email_address, address)
        cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Image inserted successfully as a BLOB into a table")
        cursor.close()

        # except sqlite3.Error as error:
        #     print("Failed to insert blob data into sqlite table", error)
        # finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("the sqlite connection is closed")

    def remove_contact (self, id):
        self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id = ?", (id,))
        self.conn.commit()

    def edit_contact (self, id, image_entry, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email_address, address):
        self.cur.execute("UPDATE contacts SET image_entry = ?, firstname = ?, lastname = ?, phone_number = ?, email_address = ?, address = ? WHERE id = ?", (image_entry, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email_address, address, id))
        empPhoto = convertToBinaryData(image_entry)
        data_tuple = (self, empPhoto, firstname, lastname, phone_number, email_address, address)
        self.cur.execute (sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
        self.conn.commit()

    def __del__ (self):
        self.conn.close()


# db = Database('store.db')
```

main program:

```
def add_contact():


    db.insertBLOB (file_name, firstname_text.get (), lastname_text.get (), phone_number_text.get (), email_address_text.get (), address_text.get ())
    contact_list.delete (0, END)
    contact_list.insert (END, file_name, firstname_text.get (), lastname_text.get (), phone_number_text.get (), email_address_text.get (), address_text.get ())
    clear_contacts ()
    populate_list ()

def open_image ():
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename (initialdir = "/", title = 'Select A File', filetypes = (('png files', '*.png'), ('jpg files', '*.jpg')))
    app.filename = file_name
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open (app.filename).resize ((80, 80), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    image_label.configure (image = image)
    image_label.image = image
    image_entry = Entry (app, textvariable = file_name)
    image_entry = {'image' : image}


app.filename = 'no_image.jpg'
file_name = 'no_image.jpg'
image_value = ImageTk.PhotoImage (Image.open ('no_image.jpg').resize ((80, 80), Image.ANTIALIAS))
image_label = Label (app, text = '', image = image_value, background = '#5D4157')
image_label.place (x = 475, y = 10)
# image_entry = Entry (app, textvariable = '', backgroundimage = 'no_image.jpg')
image_entry = Entry (app, textvariable = file_name)
image_address = ''


# First name
firstname_text = StringVar ()
firstname_label = Label (app, text = 'First Name:', font = ('bold', 16))
firstname_label.grid (row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
firstname_label.configure (background = '#5D4157')
firstname_entry = Entry (app, textvariable = firstname_text)
firstname_entry.grid (row = 1, column = 1)
firstname_entry.configure (background='#A8CABA')
```

and other inputs are like firstname
so after that i have this Error:

```
   self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index) + elements)
_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "no_image.jpg": must be active, 
anchor, end, @x,y, or a number
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the `NULL` in the `VALUES` clause?  Note that in the `VALUES` clause you have `NULL` + 6 placeholders (`?`), but there are only six columns named in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: try removing `Null` from `value` clause. Adding `Null` to your `insertion` clause makes a total of 7 values to be inserted, whereas your `DB` is only expecting 6 values at most ('cause there are six `column`s in the `database`). IF YOU KNOW WHY YOU HAVE `Null` IN THERE, please let us know :)

Comment: Thanks alot I try that but I have another Error that I dont know why it happends. i add it to end of my Q to let you see what happens after this change.

Comment: The definition of `insertBLOB()` has 7 arguments, but you called it with 6 arguments.

Comment: I know but my new Error with changes is this:  """cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_blob_query, data_tuple)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 7 supplied.     """  so if it didnt get them truely it has Error at the first not in this part. so in this part i cant undrestand how to solve it!

Comment: look at my last changes